# Facing event depreceated error in Javascript. Can anyone suggest what to do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in my react code when I am trying to run the code it is showing the event is deprecated for the event.preventDefault(). Can anyone tell me what should I do?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState("");
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);

  function createTodo() {
    event.preventDefault();
    setTodo((oldTodo) => {
      return [...oldTodo, task];
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todo App</h1>
      <form onSubmit={createTodo}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={task}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setTask(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button type="submit">Click me</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {todo.map((todos) => {
          return <li>{todos}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ERROR in src\App.js
Line 8:5:  Unexpected use of 'event'  no-restricted-globals

Comment: Declare 'event' as argument in createTodo function?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't made event an argument to createTodo, so it's being interpreted as a global, hence the warning.

Comment: If this solves your issue please accept it as an answer so it can be found easily in the future by other people.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two kinds of events here. The non-deprecated one you used in this bit of code:

```
onChange={(e) => {
    // e is event!
    setTask(e.target.value);
}}
```

To clarify, the code above is really doing this:

```
onChange={(event) => {
    setTask(event.target.value);
}}
```

But since the event object is passed as argument you can name it anything you like in your function definition:

```
onChange={(foo) => {
    // foo is event!
    setTask(foo.target.value);
}}
```

However, for readability reasons it is best to give the event object an easily recognisable name such as `event` or `e`.

Now, since you already know how to use the non-deprecated event object all you need to do is do the same thing:

```
function createTodo(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodo((oldTodo) => {
        return [...oldTodo, task];
    });
}
```